# Powershell find registry values and set them in quotes

Tags: .net, windows, powershell, registry, powershell-5.0

i want to write a script that searchs for every registry key called uninstallstring which value is not in quotes and set them into quotes.
This is what i got so far. My Problem is, that it turns the value in quotes again even if the value is still in quotes.

```
gci HKLM:\SOFTWARE\test -rec -ea SilentlyContinue |  
   % {  
      $g=get-itempropertyvalue -Path $_.PsPath -Name uninstallstring 
      IF(-NOT ($g -contains '"')){ Set-ItemProperty -Path $_.PsPath -name uninstallstring -Value "'$g'"}

   }
```

Comment: `-contains` works on collections, not on strings. You need `-match` or `$g.contains('"')`

Comment: or `-like` / `-notlike`

Comment: @gvee No, those comparisons are for wildcards.  @Protal is correct that he needs to use `String.Contains()` or `-match`.

Comment: Thanks to you all ! 
$g.contains() did it .

Comment: You should post an answer to that effect and show the working code.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 `$g -notlike "*\`"*"`

Comment: @gvee still overcomplicated: `'*"*'`

Answer (score 1):

So this works pretty well for me. Thanks to everyone!

```
gci HKLM:\SOFTWARE\test -rec -ea SilentlyContinue |  
   % {  
      $g=get-itempropertyvalue -Path $_.PsPath -Name uninstallstring 
      IF(-NOT ($g.contains('"'))){ Set-ItemProperty -Path $_.PsPath -name uninstallstring -Value "`"$g`""}

   }
```